# Cypher request to extract genealogy

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm parsing a book within neo4j and I'd like to extract genealogy out of it I have sentences like :

"A begat B,C and D"

"X begat Y, and Y begat Z, ..."

and I store that as

```
(A:word)-[:subj]->(begat:word)-[:obj]-> (B:word)
(A:word)-[:subj]->(begat:word)-[:comp]-> (C:word)

(X:word)-[:subj]->(begat:word)-[:obj]-> (Y:word)
(Y:word)-[:subj]->(begat:word)-[:obj]->  (Z:word)

(X:word)-[:NNP]->(sentence:word)
(Y:word)-[:NNP]->(sentence:word)
(Z:word)-[:NNP]->(sentence:word)
(begat:word)-[:VBG]->(sentence:word)
```

How could I write my cypher request so that neo4j server visualization give me a tree instead of one "begat" node with all the other ones linking to it ? My genealogy is on several sentences and when linking word together I add the sentenceId to the relationship maybe we could use that.

The result would look like

```
        A
  ______|_____
 |      |     |
 B      C     D
              |
              X
              |
              Y
              |
              Z
```

One more info the words are stored only once to avoid memory consumption.

Here is a sample of my data : 
http://console.neo4j.org/r/xzsazf

Many thanks

Comment: You can use http://console.neo4j.org to share a sample. The notation in your question is a bit confusing, is `(:subj)` a node or a relationship? It helps with clarity if you type it as if you were typing a cypher pattern, i.e. use `(`,`)` for nodes and `[`,`]` for relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the address, I corrected the notation I had it all mixed up

Comment: so what would be the result you want to see from your query? don't understand what you're asking for.